# sort a dict by key(key is a string with a number)

Tags: python, sorting

: trying to sort a dictionary by keys

: keys have numbers

tried doing this

```
def DictSortedKey(dictionary):
    Dict = {}
    for key in sorted(dictionary):
        Dict[key] = dictionary[key]

    return Dict


a = {"A 1": "<class-id>", "A 2": "<class-id>", "A 11": "<class-id>"}

a = DictSortedKey(a)

print(a)
```

but it returns `{'A 1': '<class-id>', 'A 11': '<class-id>', 'A 2': '<class-id>'}`

instead of `{'A 1': '<class-id>', 'A 2': '<class-id>', 'A 11': '<class-id>'}`

.

How do I make it so that it returns

`{'A 1': '<class-id>', 'A 2': '<class-id>', 'A 11': '<class-id>'}`

instead of `{'A 1': '<class-id>', 'A 2': '<class-id>', 'A 11': '<class-id>'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the way you sort the keys. Instead of sorting by its string value, sort by its integer value. Here, instead of sorting by the string `"A 11"`, we will sort by the tuple `("A", 11)`, thus we would sort first by the letter and then by the integer value (lexicographical ordering as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types)).

```
def DictSortedKey(dictionary):
    Dict = {}

    for key in sorted(dictionary, key=lambda key: (key.split()[0], int(key.split()[1]))):  # Sort by a tuple of (str, int)
        Dict[key] = dictionary[key]

    return Dict


a = {"A 1": "<class-id>", "A 3012323187": "<class-id>", "A 2": "<class-id>", "C 23": "<class-id>", "A 11": "<class-id>", "C 10001": "<class-id>", "B 4": "<class-id>"}

a = DictSortedKey(a)

print(a)
```

Output:

```
{'A 1': '<class-id>', 'A 2': '<class-id>', 'A 11': '<class-id>', 'A 3012323187': '<class-id>', 'B 4': '<class-id>', 'C 23': '<class-id>', 'C 10001': '<class-id>'}
```

---

In simpler terms, sorting by string is just like the usual word sorting in thesaurus, where `"atmosphere"` comes before `"bow"` just like `"30123231"` would come before `"4"`.

```
numbers = ["1", "30123231" "87", "101", "3444", "2", "4", "3"]

print("Sort by string value:", sorted(numbers))
print("Sort by integer value:", sorted(numbers, key=lambda num: int(num)))
print("Sort by integer value:", sorted(map(int, numbers)))
```

Output:

```
Sort by string value: ['1', '101', '2', '3', '3012323187', '3444', '4']
Sort by integer value: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '101', '3444', '3012323187']
Sort by integer value: [1, 2, 3, 4, 101, 3444, 3012323187]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I'm gonna properly learn lambdas knowing I can do more complicated stuff using it

Answer (score 1):

To guarantee dictionary ordering across various versions of Python, use the ordered dict from the built in `collections` module.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

a = {"A 1": "<class-id>", "A 2": "<class-id>", "A 11": "<class-id>"}

result = OrderedDict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda t: int(t[0].split(" ")[1])))
```

Which gives the result:

```
OrderedDict([('A 1', '<class-id>'), ('A 2', '<class-id>'), ('A 11', '<class-id>')])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the keys for your dictionary is always contain at least 1 number then you can use this:

```
a = {'A 1': '<class-id>', 'A 11': '<class-id>', 'A 2': '<class-id>', 'A 0': '<class-id>'}
sorted_a = {k: v for k, v in sorted(a.items(), key=lambda item: [int(s) for s in item[0].split() if s.isdigit()][0])}
```

it sorts a by the first number in keys